# Quiero poner una dirección o enlace a las imágenes del slider pero simplemente no me deja

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Creo que puede ser algún error en los estilos, pero no sé cual sea o donde se arregle, verifíquenlo primero, ya que poniendo las etiquetas `<a href""></a>` no me funciona.

```js
let indice = 1;

muestraSlides(indice);

function avanzaSlide(n){
    muestraSlides( indice+=n );
}

function posicionSlide(n){
    muestraSlides(indice=n);
}

setInterval(function tiempo(){
    muestraSlides(indice+=1)
},4000);

function muestraSlides(n){
    let i;
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName('miSlider');
    let barras = document.getElementsByClassName('barra');

    if(n > slides.length){
        indice = 1;
    }
    if(n < 1){
        indice = slides.length;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
        slides[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    for(i = 0; i < barras.length; i++){
        barras[i].className = barras[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    slides[indice-1].style.display = 'block';
    barras[indice-1].className += ' active';

}
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'lato';
}

.slide-contenedor{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* margin: auto; */
}

/* .miSlider {
    display: none;
    transition: 2s;
    max-height: 100vh;
} */

.miSlider img{
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    height: inherit;
    object-fit: cover;
    vertical-align: top;
    transition: 2s;
}

.direcciones{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.direcciones a{
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.direcciones a:hover{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    transition: .5s;
}

.barras{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.barra{
    cursor: pointer;
    height:2px;
    width: 25px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background: #dcdde1;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

.active{
    background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.fade{
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;    
}

@keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4;}
    to{opacity:1;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Slider</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slide-contenedor">
        <div class="miSlider fade">
          <img src="IMAGEN 1" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="miSlider fade">
            <img src="IMAGEN 2" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="miSlider fade">
            <img src="IMAGEN 3" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="direcciones">
            <a href="#" class="atras" onclick="avanzaSlide(-1)">❮</a>
            <a href="#" class="adelante" onclick="avanzaSlide(1)">❯</a>
        </div>
        <div class="barras">
            <span class="barra active" onclick="posicionSlide(1)"></span>
            <span class="barra" onclick="posicionSlide(2)"></span>
            <span class="barra" onclick="posicionSlide(3)"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: por qué pones en una etiqueta `a` un evento para tu slider?

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes. Cuando la plataforma te dice que necesitas agregas más texto, se refiere a una explicación más detallada del problema. Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega más información. ¿Qué enlaces quieres agregar y dónde? ¿Qué estilos son los que crees que están afectando? ¿Qué hace el script y qué debería hacer?

Comment: por que no le pones extensión a las imágenes?

Comment: lo que necesito esque todas las imagenes del slider al dar click en ellas redireccione a otra seccion o a otra parte

Comment: mandé el codigo completo porque nose que cambio hay que hacerle para que funcione al dar click en las imagenes